# I need to connect two table's data using a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm new to sql and I can't figure out this trigger.

First Table is **Order_Details**
which has Three rows,

```
O_Id
F_Id
Price(Int)
```

Second Table is **Payment_Details**
which has Two rows,

```
O_Id
Total_Price(Int)
```

When a order is placed, the Order_Details cretes multiple rows with different foods(F_Id) with different price (Price) but the same Order number(O_Id). Because a single order can have multiple food items

So I need a Trigger to calculate the sum of all the Food Price(Total_Price) in a Single Order.

Is there any possible trigger for this?

Comment: I assume you mean `First Table is Order_Details which has Three **COLUMNS**`,

Comment: Surely you can do the adding up as part of inserting multiple rows. Also its often better to NOT carry totals around if you can calc them on the fly as stored totals can be wrong very easily when amended manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are really the only columns you would do better to create it as a view.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Order_Details(
> O_Id int,
> F_Id int,
> Price Int);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW Payment_Details AS
> SELECT O_Id,
> SUM(Price) AS Total_Price
> FROM Order_Details
> GROUP BY O_Id;
> ```

> ```
> insert into Order_Details values
> (1,1,20),(1,2,15);
> ```

> ```
> select * from Payment_Details;
> ```
>
> ```
> O_Id | Total_Price
> ---: | ----------:
>    1 |          35
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=70c95144a0fe00208d861af69465db79)*